# C++ Finding String Length With Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c++, for-loop, strlen

I'm taking a `Comp Sci` course at the moment and one of the examples my teacher wrote on the board is as follows - The concept is to create a `string` length function which returns a `size_t` with the string length using pointer arithmetic. I understand the concept but every time I try the example my result is `0`.

```
using namespace std;

size_t strlen(const char* str);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char test[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
    cout << strlen(test);

    return 0;
}

size_t strlen(const char* str){
    int idx = 0;
    for( ; *str; str++, idx++){
        return(idx);
    }
}
```

If anyone can provide insight as to what's going wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: You `return` on the very first iteration of the loop. My guess is, you copied down the code from the board incorrectly. It was likely `for( ; *str; str++, idx++); return idx;` which is not at all the same thing. All this suggests that you may not, in fact, quite understand the concept.

Comment: P.S. You're not actually using pointer *arithmetic* with this code.

Comment: Be wary of `NULL`/`nullptr` input.

Comment: Also be wary of using the name `strlen`. Some implementations of `strlen` are [macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion), so if the `string.h` header is included, all uses of `strlen` are replaced with the `strlen` macro. Really freaky error messages result.

Answer (score 3):

```
for( ; *str; str++, idx++){
    return(idx);
}
```

Is going to return `idx` on the very first iteration.  What you need to do is let the for loop run and then return `idx`.  That would look like:

```
for( ; *str; str++, idx++){}
return(idx);
```

You could end the for statement with a `;` but I find that easy to miss.  By using an empty block of curly braces it shows that you intend to have an empty loop body

Comment: Thank you! Completely makes sense, I feel silly for asking the question now. Using loops without bodies is a new concept to me. Darn prof needs to stop writing code shorthand

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @IgorTandetnik, your loop terminates after 1 iteration

```
size_t strlen(const char* str){
    size_t idx = 0;
    for( ; *str; str++, idx++){
        return(idx); // <------ here
    }
}
```

Clang actually catches this with the `-Weverything` warning level

```
> main.cpp:15:18: warning: loop will run at most once (loop increment
> never executed) [-Wunreachable-code-loop-increment]
>     for( ; *str; str++, idx++){
>                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The fix is easy:

```
size_t strlen(const char* str){
    size_t idx = 0;
    for( ; *str; str++, idx++) {} // here       
    return(idx);    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/170177745113d95b)

Answer (score 2):

This version actually uses pointer arithmetic:

```
size_t strlen(const char* str)
{
    const char * const os = str;
    while ( *str ) ++str;
    return str - os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t strlen(const char* str){
    int idx = 0;

    while(*str++)
        idx++;

    return idx; 
}
```

Try above, and see if you get right string length.